# pointer value in main(), am getting correct output at function

Tags: c

Below is the code where I am getting the address of c at main() of instead of value:

```
int addtion(int *a, int *b, int *c) {
    c = *a + *b;
    printf("sum is :%d\n", c);
}

int main() {
    int a = 10;
    int b = 10;
    int c;
    addtion(&a, &b, &c);
    printf("%d\n", c);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that you are getting the correct ouptut? assigning 20 to `c` in `addition` doesn't affect `c` in `main`, in other words, `c` in `main` remains uninitialized.

Comment: @KeineLust He is assigning an `int` to `int *`

Comment: @machine_1, yes, thats why I say that `c` in `main` remains uninitialized, to change the value of `c` in `main`  you need to dereference `c` inside `addition`

Comment: Did you get any compiler warnings?

Comment: Your question is not clear, but if you mean why does your first printf work, the answer is that on many machines pointers and integers are the same size, so you assign an integer to a pointer and then you have printf print it as an integer, and It sort of appears to work.

Comment: thank you for reply guys, i got solution for above that i was supposed to de-reference the c so that i can get the value of c at main().

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to pass the addresses of `a` and `b` because their values are not to be changed, but to be used only. You need to de-reference `c` inside your `addtion` function to save the value of addition to what it points to:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void addtion(int a, int b, int *c) {
    *c = a + b;
    printf("sum is :%d\n", *c);
}

int main() {
    int a = 10;
    int b = 10;
    int c;
    addtion(a, b, &c);
    printf("%d\n", c);
}
```

As a final note, your `addition` function does not appear to return any value so consider using `void` instead.

Comment: Yes you are right that until we need not to change the value at actual parameters we are not supposed to send address of actual parameters. And in my program i was not de-referencing the pointer c so i was not able to get the value at main().But is there anything wrong if i send addresses of a and b and de-referencing at addtion() funcn.